# Displaying a google map in google closure

Tags: google-maps, google-closure

How can I display a map in Google Closure. There seems to be many UI widgets but none for showing a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused. Since Google Closure is a javascript library, can't you just use the Google Maps Javascript API? Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/ap/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 8,
       center: latlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
```

And then you can just change the document.getElementById() to whatever you need.

Reference: [Google Maps Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html)

Comment: No you can't as Google Closure munges the google map API variable names

Comment: @Zubair, The externs John linked in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620153/downloading-the-google-maps-api-v3) prevent Google Maps variable renaming.